# Delete cell content after enter key?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, spreadsheet

Excel I need it to delete what I type right after I press enter is this possible? This might be easy but I don't know how to.

Yes I am using this data I need it to send the data and then delete itself with the results from that data in.
This is what I have so far: "=COUNTIF(B2;C8)" so if the b2 matches c8 then it adds one and I need it to delete the b2 automatically so that I could enter new value.

Comment: Yes, this is possible with something like a `Worksheet_Change` macro. Get started on one and if you run into difficulty, come back and update your question. We'll be glad to help sort out any difficulties you run into but you should show some original effort and make an attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.ClearContents
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

Macros must be enabled for this to work!

Comment: Also would this be able to work in OpenOffice Calc too?

Comment: Is there a easyer way to do this? How about if I just fill in these search values one by one in one column and call then on each item like so "=COUNTIF(A9:A7110;C8)"  but then I just need a way to also subtract if search found in next column B.

Comment: The goal here is to make an inventory counter. I was looking online and all the free inventory programs don't do what I want. I want to just turn it on scan scan scan and for it to add each scan and compare it with the database uploaded. And then click, scan more and they would remove those stock. Thanks if you know anything.

Answer (score 1):

Go to File > Options. This will open a window, select the second tab Formulas. Check the box Enable Iterative Calculation.

Note, that this box will uncheck itself if you install updates. 
Ta da!!!